# Animate accordion height not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an accordion with hidden content that is set to `height:0`, but when I click on the toggle-firer, I want it to animate to `height:auto`, but nothing seems to be happening. **This cannot rely on any modern solutions either, such as CSS3.**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uaytq

HTML:

```
<div class="collapse-group">
    <div class="collapse-header">
      <h1>Some Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse-toggle">
        <div class="icon">&plus;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse-content">
        Check out all this filler content! Check out all this filler content! Check out all this filler content! Check out all this filler content! Check out all this filler content! Check out all this filler content! Check out all this filler content! Check out all this filler content! Check out all this filler content! Check out all this filler content! Check out all this filler content! Check out all this filler content! Check out all this filler content! Check out all this filler content! Check out all this filler content! 
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.collapse-toggle').click(function () {
    var that = $(this).find('.collapse-content');
    that.animate({'height':'auto'}, 500);
});
```

CSS:

```
.wrap {
  background:#999999;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:500px;
}
.collapse-toggle {
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -30px;
  bottom: -60px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.collapse-toggle .icon {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 80px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #f79727;
  background: white;
  z-index: 9;
}
.collapse-group {
  *zoom: 1;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 2em;
}
.collapse-group:before,
.collapse-group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.collapse-group:after {
  clear: both;
}
.collapse-group.we-create {
  padding-top: 0;
}
.collapse-group.orange {
  background: #f79727;
}
.collapse-group.orange .section-headline,
.collapse-group.orange .section-tagline {
  color: white;
}
.collapse-group.orange .icon {
  color: white;
  background: #f79727;
}
.collapse-group .collapse-content {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to know the height or use the height approach, try the following

http://jsfiddle.net/19byov36/ or http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vtsLd

```
$('.collapse-toggle').click(function () {
    var that = $(this).next();
    that.slideToggle();
});
```

or you can do it all in one line

```
$(this).next().slideToggle();
```

CSS

```
.collapse-group .collapse-content {
  display: none;
}
```

This works for the provided code, if the content is not the next element you can traverse to the parent then find the content

```
$(this).closest('.collapse-group').find('.collapse-content');
```

In your original code

```
$(this).find('.collapse-content');
```

will not work because collapse-content is not a child of the toggle. I also removed the height 0 on the content and changed it to a display none

Answer (score 0):

You can also use slideDown and use height: auto. See here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kdw34tL4/1/)

```
$('.collapse-toggle').click(function () {
    var that = $(this).parent().find('.collapse-content');
    that.slideDown(500);
});
```

Also had this to your css:

```
.collapse-group .collapse-content {
    height:auto;
    display:none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

If you want to toggle the element you just need to change `that.slideDown(500);` for `that.slideToggle(500);`

You also need to include parent() before find() so it can look for the class .collapse-content in the right place.

Comment: all the `.collpase-content` sections have a variable height though, so setting a fixed height of say 150 wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You DONT need to define a height. Try revising your JS so that you're simply adding and removing a class on toggle. Height "auto" WILL work and css transition will show it properly. The problem is with the current JS in your codepen. Try something like this:

```
var $accordion = jQuery('.accordion');

$accordion.on('click', '.toggle', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    var $thisToggle = jQuery(e.currentTarget);
    $thisToggle.parent().toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

Then you can rely on CSS and the ".toggle" class to create your effect.